# How to click relative to a window/application in python and how to handle multiple scripts that click?

Tags: python, automation

Is there any way to click relative to an open window? For example, clicking a set amount of pixels to the right/up/left/down of an open tab of google chrome? I know how to click using absolute coordinates, or click on something that matches an image file, but I haven't been able to find anything regarding relative clicking.

Another part to this - when automating some process on a computer that uses the mouse or keyboard to input commands, if you run two or more of the same script, is there a possibility that the commands interrupt each other? Like if you move the mouse and then click, but another script moves it again before the first one is allowed to click? Is there an easy solution for this? What my mind jumps to first is using a queuing process similar to handling multiple processes in an OS.

Comment: second question: yes, two scripts at the same time may interrupt each other. Simply don't run at the same time but one after another.

Comment: on Window you can use [PyGetWindow](https://github.com/asweigart/pygetwindow) to get window's position. The same author created `pyautogui` which can control mouse and keyboard so it can click in any place. On Linux you would have to use external programs (like `wmctrl`) to get window's location. Eventually you can try to use module `XLib` (or similar to get it). I don't use Mac but probably it could also have `wmctrl`. But I don't know program/module which can get position of tab in Chrome/Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library pyautogui.
I put an example here:

```
import pyautogui as pya
start = pya.locateCenterOnScreen('start.png')#If the file is not a png file it will not work
print(start)
pya.moveTo(start)#Moves the mouse to the coordinates of the image
#even you can make click with
pya.click(button='left',clicks=2,x=start.x,y=start.y) # you can do two click on the image
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future coming across this post, using Python to move their mouse relative to a specific windows coordinates:

**EASIEST WAY**

(Requires pyautogui & pywin32 (win32gui successor))

Step 1: Get the HWND or the 'ID' of the 'Active Window' you want to move your mouse relative to:

```
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'Untitled - Notepad')
```

Step 2: Now let's get the global X and Y coordinates of the top left and bottom right corner of this app to determine where it is on your screen at the moment:

```
x0, y0, x1, y1 = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
```

You can also get the dimensions of the window here as well:

```
w = x1 - x0  # width
h = y1 - y0  # height
```

Step 3: We only need the X0 and Y0 (top left corner global coordinates on our screen), so return those if you put this in its own method

Step 4: All you have to do now is create a custom method to moveMouse(x, y) which takes your relative coordinates in as an argument, and translates them using the newly acquired X0, Y0 coordinates. You're basically just adding the offset required to be 'relative' to the active window and that offset is acquired by determining the top left corners x, y position.

```
def MoveMouse(x, y):
    x0, y0 = GetMyWindowSize() # Method I created to return the GetWindowRect() values

pyautogui.moveTo(x + bsX, y + bsY)
return
```

Good luck! If you're not restricted to Python, AHK (Auto Hotkey) is also worth checking out for automation of mouse and keyboard inputs. There are native methods to recreate this functionality.